# Keep dropdown menu open when moving mouse away?

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, zurb-foundation

I am using zurb foundation 4 in a codeigniter site and in the desktop version I have the login top right as a drop down b ut when the mouse is moved away from the content of the drop down menu it closes, I would like to know if it is possible to keep it open unless the user clicks somewhere else on the page.

Please see the example of what i am explaining on the foundation website docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html

I just need to edit that example so that the drop down doesnt close when the mouse is moved away.

I am using the basic code below:

```
<nav class="top-bar">
 <ul class="title-area">
 <!-- Title Area -->
<li class="name">
  <h1><a href="test">M450N</a></h1>
</li>
<!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
<li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
</ul>

<section class="top-bar-section">
<!-- Left Nav Section -->
<ul class="left">
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="about">About</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="index">Events</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>      
</ul>

<!-- Right Nav Section THIS IS THE PROBLEM SECTION -->
<ul class="right">
<li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Login</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="has-dropdown">
      <div class="panel">
      <input type = "text" value = "Username"/><br />
      <input type = "text" value = "Password"/><br />
      <input type = "Submit" value = "Login"/></div>
     </li>
 </ul>
 </section>
 </nav>
```

**Foundation CSS:** http://pastebin.com/iRpqtY2G

**Main CSS**: http://pastebin.com/fBExPY1j

Comment: Your question contains neither css or javascript that might be responsible for your described errant behavior. Please provide more data.

Comment: the reason why I didnt include them is that the only css that can be applicable is the standard foundation javascript and css files, its not an error Itsa wandering if i could add this to my site here is the foundation css file: [CSS LINK](http://pastebin.com/iRpqtY2G). Thanks.

Comment: PLease see the example on the foundation docs showing this is the standard way for it to work but I want to change it so that the dropdown doesnt close when the mouse moves away http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS property ":active" instead of ":hover"

Use

```
ul.dropdown:active {
    // css properties
}
```

Instead of

```
ul.dropdown:active {
    // css properties
}
```

May be it help to:
Replace :hover to :active

```
.top-bar-section ul li > a:hover {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button:hover {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button.secondary:hover {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button.success:hover {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button.alert:hover {
.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover {
```

To

```
.top-bar-section ul li > a:hover,.top-bar-section ul li > a:active {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button:hover,.top-bar-section ul li > a.button:active {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button.secondary:hover,.top-bar-section ul li > a.button.secondary:active {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button.success:hover, .top-bar-section ul li > a.button.success:active {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button.alert:hover,.top-bar-section ul li > a.button.alert:active {
.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover,.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):active {
```

This code helps you to add "Onclick" functionality as well. If you want only "onclick" functionality then use below mention lines

```
.top-bar-section ul li > a:active {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button:active {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button.secondary:active {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button.success:active {
.top-bar-section ul li > a.button.alert:active {
.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):active {
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I believe in the code the instead of is supposed to be `ul.dropdown:hover` correct? however I couldn't find this in the foundation css and I tried creating it in my main.css to overwrite it to no avail here is the foundation.css code if you could kindly point me in the right direction: [CSS LINK](http://pastebin.com/iRpqtY2G) Thanks.

Comment: May be it help to:
Replace :hover to :active